# How to fill a matrix recursively with 1's and zeroes such that the diagonal is zeroes and there are N 1's in the other elements?

Tags: matrix, graph-theory

for example I if there are N=4 1's i would like to fill the 3x3 matrix with each permutation symmetric with 2 1's in the upper and lower triangles each. I will get [010,101,010],[001,001,110], and [011,100,100].

Comment: Why do you need to do it recursively? Solving a problem recursively mean you can divide the problem into the same but smaller problem, solve the smaller first and then use recursion to get to the bigger step by step. But that doesn't seem to be the case here, can't think on a way to have it that way. Tell me how have you thought on solving it using recursion and maybe I could help you

Comment: Sorry about that, I guess I don't mean to do recursion, just a way of getting all permutations of a 0, 1 matrix with only a certain amount of 1's and all 0's along the diagonal.

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
void matrixFill(int[,] m, int n)
{
    m[n-1, n-1] = 0;
    if (n > 1)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n-1; i++)
        {
            m[i, n-1] = 1;
            m[n-1, i] = 1;
        }
        matrixFill(m , n-1);
    }
}
```

Each level of recursion sets one diagonal element and the remaining row/column intersecting in this element.

---

**2nd attempt without explicit iteration:**

```
//  1st call matrixFill2(m , n-1, n-1)
void matrixFill2(int[,] m, int x, int y)
{
    if ((x >= 0) && (y >= 0))
    {
        m[x, y] = (x == y) ? 0 : 1;
        matrixFill2(m, x-1, y);
        matrixFill2(m, x, y-1);
        matrixFill2(m, x-1, y-1);
    }
}
```

This version will set matrix cells more than once. Row/column indices stay untouched or are decreased. Therefore, recursion will eventually terminate.

Answer (score 0):

```
#Figured it out
from __future__ import print_function
import itertools
import numpy as np

N = 4
S = N*(N-1)/2
E = 3

which = np.array(list(itertools.combinations(range(S), E)))
grid = np.zeros((len(which), S), dtype="int8")
grid[np.arange(len(which))[None].T, which] = 1

for perm in range(len(grid)):
    grid_num = perm
    A = np.zeros((N,N))
    counter = 0
    for i in range(N):
        for j in range(i):
            A[i][j] = grid[grid_num][counter]
            A[j][i] = grid[grid_num][counter]
            counter = counter + 1
    print()
    print(A)
```